# Update yarn.lock after removing a workspace

Tags: yarnpkg

Suppose I have a monorepo using the standard [workspace](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/) structure:

```
monorepo
|- package.json
|- yarn.lock
|- packages
   |- package_a
   |- package_b
```

I want to completely get rid of `package_a` while also updating the yarn.lock accordingly.

The following doesn't update the lockfile:

```
$ rm -rf packages/package_a
$ yarn install
```

Running this in the root of the monorepo doesn't work either:

```
$ yarn remove -W package_a
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
```

This does work, but bumps *all* packages where the range allows which is not desired.

```
$ rm -rf packages/package_a
$ yarn upgrade
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In the `yarn remove` documentation, it doesn't seem to have an option `-W`. Have you tried just `yarn remove package_a` ? hhttps://yarnpkg.com/cli/remove

Comment: I'm also curious as the documentation states that ```yarn remove``` updates yarn.lock automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstand your question... But it appears that you need to include each `package` in your `package.json` as mentioned with each `workspace` here: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/.

**Needed in `package.json`:**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "packages": ["package_a", "package_b"]
}
```

I'm guessing this is why you are getting the error  `error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.` when attempting `yarn remove -W package_a`. When it is included in the `package.json` then just `yarn remove package_a` this will also update your `yarn.lock` automatically.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/remove

Comment: `ut it appears that you need to include each package in your package.json`

You don't have to. You can also use blobs to spesicfy the workspaces, or just rely on the default directory structure (`packages/*`).

`When it is included in the package.json then just yarn remove package_a this will also update your yarn.lock automatically.`

this will fail as well. `yarn remove` removes dependencies not workspaces.

Comment: I believe you'd have to select the workspace first then remove. If you want to remove a package: ```yarn workspace web-project remove some-package``` the example would remove ```some-package``` from ```packages/web-project/package.json```.